# Require.js optional module loading

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am looking to integrate Require.JS into my project which requires the ability to switch dependencies based on the client.

Currently I have some background processing that is performed using web-workers, in the future I would like the option to have the processing performed on a server which should involve just replacing a module.

Currently the only approach I can think to have the following pseudo code in my main script file :

```
var modules = [];
// This would be done with Modernizr or with a simple hasOwnProperty check
if(window.hasFeature('web-workers') {
    modules = ["other-dependencies", "webworker-calc"];
} else {
    modules = ["other-dependencies", "server-calc"];
}
require(modules, function (deps, calc) { // Code goes here };
```

Is there a cleaner approach to doing this? Can I leverage Require.JS more than I am in the above example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the config for require.js by ether calling `require.config` or settings a global require object before fetching require.js source file:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'calc-lib': window.hasFeature('web-workers') ? 'webworker-calc' : 'server-calc'
    }
});
```

Or:

```
<script>
    var require = { paths: {...} }
</script>
<script src="require.js" data-main="script/main"></script>
```

and then require it in a "normal" way and [r.js](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/) compressable way:

```
require(["other-dependencies", "calc-lib"], function (deps, calc) { 
    // Code goes here
});
```

As long as the "api" for both the files is the same you will not have to make any other precautions.

Comment: You should look into the config options and especially the shim options: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim